# Expo Firebase google login: 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am using Firebase to sign in using google account in expo react native. When I am in the development mode and working with my app locally (without building the standalone app) it works properly and I am able to connect. When I create the standalone app It says:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

[image]

I have searched and I think that the problem may be because of the package name. My app.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "SU AUC",
    "slug": "su-auc",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/SU_Logo.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/highResWelcomeScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],

    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.SU.SUAPP",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "reservedClientId": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.SU.SUAPP",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
  }
}
```

So, what is the solution to this?

Comment: You didn't include your redirect URI (configured in the console) nor what URI the login process is trying to redirect you to, nor js console errors nor networking calls. Going to be hard to troubleshoot complex moving parts without the basics. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not know any of these to include them!

Comment: @OmarDiaa Can you find the solution bro? I'm facing the same issue